# Gathering Application Information.

Tags: windows-7, gui, user-interface

I am looking for an application that will allow the user to gather information about a targeted application. For example, I want to generate a list of UI component ID's for an application.

To explain this further: I have a windows form application I have created in C# - I want to identify the ID assigned to a text box (for example: tbName). Is there any application that can identify this information?

Kind Regards,
JH

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[AutoIt](http://www.autoitscript.com/site/)'s main distribution comes with a ["Window Info" tool](http://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/intro/au3spy.htm) that tells you what you're after. Someone in the AutoIt forums claims to have made a [better version](http://www.autoitscript.com/forum/topic/126716-control-viewer-autoit-window-info-tool/), as well. I haven't used the latter, though.